# string concatenation doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++

(win7; gcc 4.8.2 (cygwin))

The code fragment below yields `count error Pointer\\` instead of `( "Pointer" )`. Is there anything I can do to get the correct result?

```
  virtual string toString() const { 
     return "Pointer";
  }
  virtual string write() const {
     string str = "( " + '"' + toString() + '"' + " )";
     return str;
  };
```

Comment: What is producing that error?  The compiler?  Runtime?

Comment: Is it possible there is a derived type that is overriding either of thos emethods?

Comment: @Smac89: No, `toString()` _should_ be `const`. Not sure why you suggested making it non-`const`, especially as that has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's clear up a few things:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| Expression  | Type           | Type as operator arg  |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|  toString() |  std::string   |  std::string          |
|  "( "       |  char const[3] |  char const*          |
|  '"'        |  char          |  char                 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

**These are not all "strings".**

The main issue here is that `"( " + '"'` does not do what you think it does. "Adding" a `char` to a `const char*` does not build a larger string; it adds a number to the string literal's pointer value. In doing this, you make a new pointer that points to… well… nowhere useful. In fact you're invoking *undefined behaviour* by incrementing the pointer so far.

It's a bit like this:

```
char const* whatYouAreDoing()
{
   char const* a = "( ";
   char b = '"';

   int c = b;
   assert(c == 34);  // assuming ASCII 
   a += c;           // whoops!

   return a;         // this pointer is now nonsense
}
```

Generally, if you want to "build" a string, you can use stream formatting:

```
virtual string write() const
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "( " << '"' << toString() << '"' << " )";
   return ss.str();
}
```

Or, in this case, since you actually don't need all those literals, the following will be fine:

```
virtual string write() const
{
   return "( \"" + toString() + "\" )";
}
```

Comment: You have to remaind that `"( "` is not of type `std::string` but of type `const char*`. And `'"'` is of type `char` so you will increase the pointer `const char*`. And that's not what you want.

Comment: @sleepy42: Actually, string literals have type `char const[N]`. That aside, is this clearer now?

Comment: Completly correct (but in this case the `const char[3]` of `"( "` should be converted into a `const char*` because then an `operator+` can be used).

Comment: @sleepy42: Yes, as my answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a string as first summand and to be safe you also need some braces. Make sure that all summands are strings (maybe after conversion).

Okay, that is not entirely true, also operators like `+ (std::string&, consts char*)` are fine if such things exist. But, I hope you get the idea. You have to make sure that the intended `+`-operations are used, i.e. that ones from the `string`-class.

See the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string toString() { 
    return "Pointer";
}
string write() {
    string str = string("( ") + '"' + (toString() + '"') + " )";
    return str;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test:>>" << write() << "<<\n";
  return 0;
}
```