# What's the behaviour of "" + number and why it compile?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The code successfully compiles it but I can't understand why, for certain values of number, the program crashes and for other values it doesn't. Could someone explain the behavior of adding a `long int` with a `char*` that the compiler uses?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long int number=255;
    std::cout<< "Value 1 : " << std::flush << ("" + number) << std::flush << std::endl;
    number=15155;
    std::cout<< "Value 2 : " << std::flush << ("" + number) << std::flush << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test results:

```
Value 1 : >                                                                            
Value 2 : Segmentation fault
```

Note: I'm not looking for a solution on how to add a string with a number.

Comment: There's a duplicate for this surely

Comment: Intuitively I would say `""` returns the address of the first element of a litteral empty string; then you add `number` to that address; then `operator<<` attempts to dereference that new address to read a string, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The dupe explains what happens when you add a `char`. Your's is a simpler case of that, since `char` is promoted to `int` first.

Comment: For a more visual explanation of this phenomenon: replace `""` with `"Hello, World!"` and `number=255;` with `number=7;`

Comment: @stef Thank's for the explanation that resolved my problem

Comment: @cigien I've turned the dupes the other way round. It should always be from the specific case to the more generic one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, I see. I was wondering what that was about :p reordering the dupe definitely makes more sense, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Another question involving adding a character to a string literal, similar to the former duplicate: [string concatenation doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801013/string-concatenation-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: Probable duplicate, but it feels wrong to redirect a question with a positive score to one with a negative score: [Why can you add an integer to a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299156/why-can-you-add-an-integer-to-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `""` is a `const char[1]` array, which *decays* into a `const char*` pointer to the first element of the array (in this case, the string literal's `'\0'` nul terminator).

Adding an integer to a pointer performs **pointer arithmetic**, which will advance the memory address in the pointer by the specified number of elements of the type the pointer is declared as (in this case, `char`).

So, in your example, `... << ("" + number) << ...` is equivalent to `... << &""[number] << ...`, or more generically:

```cpp
const char *ptr = &""[0];
ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(
    reinterpret_cast<const uintptr_t>(ptr)
    + (number * sizeof(char))
);
... << ptr << ...
```

Which means you are going out of bounds of the array when `number` is any value other than 0, thus your code has *undefined behavior* and anything could happen when `operator<<` tries to dereference the invalid pointer you give it.

Unlike in many scripting languages, `("" + number)` is not the correct way to convert an integer to a string in C++.  You need to use an explicit conversion function instead, such as [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    long int number = 255;
    std::cout << "Value 1 : " << std::flush << std::to_string(number) << std::flush << std::endl;
    number = 15155;
    std::cout << "Value 2 : " << std::flush << std::to_string(number) << std::flush << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can simply let [`std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) handle that conversion for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long int number = 255;
    std::cout<< "Value 1 : " << std::flush << number << std::flush << std::endl;
    number = 15155;
    std::cout<< "Value 2 : " << std::flush << number << std::flush << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic is the culprit.

A `const char*` is accepted by `operator<<`, but will not point to a valid memory address in your example.

If you switch on `-Wall`, you will see a compiler warning about that:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:59: warning: array subscript 255 is outside array bounds of 'const char [1]' [-Warray-bounds]
    6 |     std::cout<< "Value 1 : " << std::flush << ("" + number) << std::flush << std::endl;
      |                                                           ^
main.cpp:8:59: warning: array subscript 15155 is outside array bounds of 'const char [1]' [-Warray-bounds]
    8 |     std::cout<< "Value 2 : " << std::flush << ("" + number) << std::flush << std::endl;
      |                                                           ^
Value 1 :  q
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436d3ccb67824fa1)